# How to use static html page in moovweb?

Tags: moovweb

I have added one `index.html` page at the root of `asset` folder in moovweb.

And on click of button I am trying to open the html page.

Whereas I am getting page cannot be loaded message.

How to access the local html page in moovweb?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the asset folder you need to define the static path on the config.json file

```
{
"host_map": [
    "my mapping => www.mymapping"
],
"static_paths": {
    "/newpage" : "index.html"
}}
```

With the mapping you can reference the page via mlocal.mysite.com/newpage.

Also, I'd recommend you to read the following content about static assets:
http://developer.moovweb.com/docs/cloud/static_asset_delivery

Cheers,

JC